# RxJS exhaustMap not behaving as expected

Tags: rxjs

I am applying exhaustMap to an observable from which two projected observables get created.  The 2nd of the two projected observables should not begin emitting until after the first projected observable completes.  So I would expect the output observable to emit the items from both projected observables.  But for some reason, the 2nd observable is being ignored.  Notice that the 2nd projected observable does not begin emitting until 7 seconds have passed -- which is well past the point at which the first projected observable has emitted its last item.  Here is my code sample:

```
import { from } from 'rxjs'; 
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { map, mergeMap, exhaustMap, delay, mergeAll } from 'rxjs/operators';

const getData = (param) => {
  if (param == 'a') {
    return interval(1000).pipe(
      map(val => param + '-' + val.toString()),
      take(4),
      delay(1000)
    )
  }
  else if (param == 'b') {
    return interval(1000).pipe(
      map(val => param + '-' + val.toString()),
      take(4),
      delay(7000)
    )
  }
}

// using exhaustMap
from(['a','b']).pipe(
  exhaustMap(param => getData(param))
).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for the behavior of `concatMap`.

Comment: @BizzyBob  No, I knew about concatMap, I was just trying to get a better understanding of exhaustMap, and my confusion has now been cleared up.  Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: After Fan Cheung cleared up my misunderstanding, I realized that any code fragment which tries to demonstrate exhaustMap in a meaningful way would need to set up a *source* observable which emits items with some time interval separating those items.  For an example of that, look at this article (and look at the "Playground" code fragment):   https://indepth.dev/reference/rxjs/operators/exhaust-map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of `exhaustMap` is once triggered it will execute its inner observable first until its completion and during that time emission from the source observable will be ignored. So in your case `b` will be ignored, when source emit `b`, `exhaustMap` is still not yet completed

Comment: Notice that the 2nd projected observable does not begin emitting until 7 seconds have elapsed, which is well after the the 1st projected observable has completed.  But perhaps you're saying that in order for the 2nd projected observable to not be ignored, the *source* observable cannot emit its 2nd item until after the first projected observable has completed.  Is that what you're saying?

Comment: OK, yes, I confirmed that it's when the *source* observable emits its 2nd item -- that has to happen after the first projected observable completes.

Comment: glad it helps u solve the problem